# MySQL backup is interrupted when the same DB is queried upon

Tags: mysql, powershell

I am taking MySQL backup using Powershell script. All works fine but when i query the same DB it hangs up. How to lock the database while the backup is going on?

**&cmd /c $MySQL_Dump_Path -h $mysql_server -port=$mysql_port -u $mysql_user --password=$mysql_password --routines --single-transaction --quick --no-autocommit --no-tablespaces $dbname| Out-File -FilePath ".\Backup\$Dump" -Encoding UTF8**

Comment: "... when i query the same DB it hangs up." It looks like already locked?

Answer (score 0):

You can add --lock-tables or the real brute way --lock-all-tables during the dump.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_lock-all-tables

edit: but this will lock the query call to the system as long as the dump is running.

Comment: I tried --lock-tables abd queried the database still getting the sane problem.

Comment: hm, do you have really large tables (over the capacity of your RAM on the server)? if not, try the "--skip-quick" option forcing the dump process to pull all values into memory before dumping and thus avoiding locks. A side question, did you mix innoDB and mysiam schema types?

Comment: I have innoDB all throughout. I have a database of size around 2 Gb.